# pg_search exact match of search terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

When trying to find "Harrison Ford" in a document, pg_search will return any text that contains 'Harrison' and 'Ford', for example:

```
  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, :against => [:first_name, :last_name]
```

*People.search_by_full_name("Harrison Ford")*

can return:

> George Harrison drives a Ford Focus

How can I make sure only exact matches of `'Harrison Ford'` will return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`pg_search`** normalization](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#normalization), or basically **[ranking search results](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html)** in Postgres. I did not even use normalization factor in the following examples:

```
SELECT ts_rank_cd(vector,query) as rank 
FROM 
  to_tsvector('simple','George Harrison drives a Ford Focus') as vector,
  to_tsquery('simple','Harrison & Ford') as query;
```

Output 1:

```
   rank    
-----------
 0.0333333
(1 row)
```

If you have `Harrison` and `Ford` together - rank will be higher:

```
SELECT ts_rank_cd(vector,query) as rank
FROM
  to_tsvector('simple','Harrison Ford drives a car') as vector,
  to_tsquery('simple','Harrison & Ford') as query;
```

Output 2:

```
 rank 
------
  0.1
(1 row)
```

If you `ORDER BY rank DESC` all you search results, you will get what you need, because all the search words which are next to each other will the highest `rank` and will be at the top of your search result list.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the normalization algorithm choices.  What threshold do I set to disregard anything other than an exact match?

Comment: the point here is that words which are next to each other will have the highest rank if you `ORDER BY rank DESC` - you will get to the top what you need; in my example I did not even use normalization factor @Ashbury

Comment: The problem is that this could still return a series of near matches (and no exact matches) ordered by how close it is to the original.  Even if I took the top result there's no guarantee its an exact match.

Comment: @Ashbury if you are looking for exact **phrase** matching - maybe you need to check [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html) not full text searh

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do full_text search then use pattern matching on the results.  pg_search with tvector takes about ~11ms, then pattern matching the results is 7ms VS pattern matching the full table (460ms).  Saving 442ms (in my little test)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the space character by <=> in the query search term as follows:

```
query.gsub!(' ', '<=>')
search_by_full_name(query)
```